# Asp.net MVC User Control ViewData

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewdata, viewusercontrol

When a controller renders a view based on a model you can get the properties from the ViewData collection using the indexer (ie. ViewData["Property"]).  However, I have a shared user control that I tried to call using the following:

```
return View("Message", new { DisplayMessage = "This is a test" });
```

and on my Message control I had this:

```
<%= ViewData["DisplayMessage"] %>
```

I would think this would render the DisplayMessage correctly, however, null is being returned.  After a heavy dose of tinkering around, I finally created a "MessageData" class in order to strongly type my user control:

```
public class MessageControl : ViewUserControl<MessageData>
```

and now this call works:

```
return View("Message", new MessageData() { DisplayMessage = "This is a test" });
```

and can be displayed like this:

```
<%= ViewData.Model.DisplayMessage %>
```

Why wouldn't the DisplayMessage property be added to the ViewData (ie. ViewData["DisplayMessage"]) collection without strong typing the user control?  Is this by design?  Wouldn't it make sense that ViewData would contain a key for "DisplayMessage"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method

```
ViewData.Eval("DisplayMessage")
```

should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Of course after I create this question I immediately find the answer after a few more searches on Google

http://forums.asp.net/t/1197059.aspx

Apparently this happens because of the wrapper class.  Even so, it seems like any property passed should get added to the ViewData collection by default.

I really need to stop answering my own questions :(